# Emulate UDP/TCP/IP connections of 40,000 or more

Tags: networking, tcp

I need to simulate a massive amount of TCP/IP ethernet traffic. For example, I want to simulate the environment that an ISP has where there might be 40,000 different IP addresses sending TCP/UDP IP traffic to different remote hosts. This is my ideal setup:

**Traffic generator - > the device I want to test (one inbound interface and one outbound interface) - > traffic receiver.**

The device I want to test is a network traffic monitor/QOS appliance. It effectively sits 'in-line', one interface would be connected to the traffic generator and the other interface connected to the traffic receiver. This in-line interface is effectively a bridge and is not assigned an IP address. It can monitor & apply QOS rules on all traffic passing over that bridge interface.

Layer 4 control is important, so that I can set port numbers (80, 443, 22 etc). Layer 7 application information would be ideal as the device I am testing also does deep packet inspection.

Methods I have already tried include using iperf but in order to simulate 40,000 IP addresses I would need to configure 40,000 virtual interfaces on both the traffic generator and the traffic receiver manually, and I have found that iperf is limited to about 1000 simultaneous connections(on my set up). I have also tried replaying large PCAP files, but then I do not have control over the packets to test QOS capabilities.

Other software/solutions I have looked into are:
http://mininet.org/ (can't handle the amount of connections I need).
[ns-3](http://mininet.org/)

I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are commercial products for this kind of thing.  Short of a home-brew setup with a combination of apache bench, siege, and tcpreplay (which would take significant effort to implement).

See www.spirent.com or www.ixiacom.com.